# Obtain the client source IP over an HTTPS communication with a ONE Armed Load balancer

Tags: https, load-balancer

I have 4 linux application servers that are load balanced in One Arm mode over a HTTPS communication.

There is the need to keep track of the source IP of the client invoking one of the servers through the load balancer. As per the one armed configuration, the source IP of the clients is masked.

With a standard plain HTTP communication we could keep track of the source IP by analysing the x-forwarded field of the HTTP header, but how could we reach the same goal during a HTTPS session?

Please note that SSL is terminated by the servers and not by the above load balancer.